# Facets rendering on all pages irrespective of value dynamicaaly form contextual filter in views

Tags: views, search

I m trying to add facets using facets module in drupal 8. i have created listing of all products using views page. on listing page, facets are showing properly as per brand information added from admin panel.

All products listing Page:

[image]

but when i go to the detail page of every individual product,facet blcok show only single value of that brand only. check below image for more reference:

[image]

Here on detail page , i want to show complete list of facets as shown in first image. how to do that??? any idea??

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is the default behaviour, where the facets are filtered based on the result set.
What you want may not be achievable OOB.
But this is not a bug, it is a correctly working behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..do you know how make that checkbox selectable when we land to details page of a brand as mentioned in second image..

Comment: I would recommend linking to the second page. Making the checkbox checked, wont be easy.
Facets read GET params, and check the checkboxes accordingly.